# Anyone else have issues with Amazon Lex integrations not understanding a spoken slot type value in Connect?

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am working on an IVR solution that collects a caller's diagnosed mental illness. So far, all of them are accepted fine with the exception of schizophrenia. I have spelled it every way I know how. Any suggestions?

I tried adding schizophrenia, Schizo phrenia, skitzo phrenia, skitzo fren ee ya, and many more variations. However, whenever schizophrenia is said, it defaults the caller instead of picking up the intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Transcribe service in AWS (https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/home?region=us-west-2) you can test what transcribe is detecting. I've started using this recently to get the variations for an intent or slot.

Interestingly after the first attempt at schizophrenia (detected as "Free NIA") the rest of my attempts were all detected successfully.

Comment: The Transcribe service understands me saying Schizophrenia - so that is interesting. I am going to add "Free Nia" to my list of utterances and see if that works.